decimal.Parse("00.01") sometimes returns 0.01 and sometimes 1
I have this code:
public static decimal GetActivityQuantity(int durationInMinutes)
{
    if(durationInMinutes >= 1440)
    {
        return 24;
    }
    // Hours and minutes, NOT DECIMAL! 2h30mn is 2.30, not 2.50
    TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(durationInMinutes);
    string durationStr = new DateTime(duration.Ticks).ToString("HH.mm");
    decimal result = decimal.Parse(durationStr);
    return result;
}

Like the comment says, I have to turn a duration of 150minutes into 2.30, not into 2.50h, because the notation is in hours and minutes, not a real decimal. The result still has to be a decimal datatype though, so the output is a decimal.
The code above results in result being 1 when I run this in a unit test.
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(0, 0)]
        [InlineData(1, 0.01)]
        [InlineData(2, 0.02)]
        [InlineData(20, 0.20)]
        [InlineData(30, 0.30)]
        [InlineData(45, 0.45)]
        [InlineData(59, 0.59)]
        [InlineData(60, 1.00)]
        [InlineData(61, 1.01)]
        [InlineData(80, 1.20)]
        [InlineData(90, 1.30)]
        [InlineData(120, 2.00)]
        [InlineData(720, 12)]
        [InlineData(1439, 23.59)]
        [InlineData(1440, 24)]
        [InlineData(2000, 24)]
        [InlineData(10000, 24)]
        public void ShouldNotReturnError(int durationInMinutes, decimal expectedResult)
        {
            decimal result = CiceroHelper.GetActivityQuantity(durationInMinutes);

            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
        }



What I really don't understand is that it somehow still returns 0.01 when I run it in dotnetfiddle
    TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    string durationStr = new DateTime(duration.Ticks).ToString("HH.mm");
    decimal result = decimal.Parse(durationStr);
    Console.WriteLine(result);


When I change the point to a comma here:
string durationStr = new DateTime(duration.Ticks).ToString("HH.mm");
// to
string durationStr = new DateTime(duration.Ticks).ToString("HH,mm");

then it's the opposite, the unit test passed and returns 0.01 while the dotnetfiddle code returns 1.
What's going on here? I really don't get it. Those unit tests passed before, now they fail in VS and when running dotnet test in the CLI.

Commas and periods (,, .) have special meaning in numbers and either can be used as the decimal separator depending on culture. In a culture that uses the period as the decimal separator, the thousands separator is often the comma and will be ignored when parsing strings to numbers.

^ decimal.Parse(durationStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) This is also mentioned in the documentation

I'm sure you probably have a good reason to represent times as a decimal number but it isn't and shouldn't be.

It is most probably due to Culture setting. try specifying CultureInfo, like decimal.Parse("00,01", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))

FWIW you can likely skip the DateTime creation: duration.ToString(@"hh\.mm");

why on earth would you do that in the first place? whenever you feel the need to write a comment like "// Hours and minutes, NOT DECIMAL! 2h30mn is 2.30, not 2.50"  you're usually doing something you shouldn't do :-)  there is a reason why we use standards on this planet. hours and minutes are separated by a colon.

Yes, I agree, but it is the required input needed by a third party legacy software that we write data to :-(

The descimal separator is culture-specific (in some cultures . character is decimal separator and in some - group separator, see NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator and NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator), one way to mitigate that is always use a specific culture:
// The default for InvariantInfo is ".", so the following
// will be treated as 0.01
decimal.Parse("00.01", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


But why did it work before the, I didn't change anything, but I assume that it means something on my computer changed the culture then?

@JFlex yes, the default culture used by the app has changed for some reason, there could be multiple reasons for that, for example the culture settings on the machine has changed.
